# JS - Comparing 2 Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm creating table view based on a JSON feed, so one of the biggest is while my labels(row) stays consistent, the table data on my cols changes

Please refer to the image below

[image]

As you can see, on the 2nd record value 1:Three should be placed on col 1

This is my array of objects:

```
const label = [{label: 'test1', labelId:'1'},{label: 'test2', labelId:'2'}]
const cols = [
            [{labelId:'1', value:'One'},{labelId:'2', value:'Two'}],
            [{labelId:'1', value:'Three'}],
            [{labelId:'2', value:'Four'}]
         ]
```

I wanna be able to compare them so I can indicate which one that doesn't have corresponding label. Thus i'll be able to replace them by empty `<td></td>`

So as one of the suggestion, here's my attempt:

```
    const labelCols = cols.map(col => {
        const arrayOfMatch = labels.findIndex(label => label.labelId === col.labelId);
        console.log(col)
        if(arrayOfMatch !== 1) { //matching label exists
        return { ...col, ...labels[arrayOfMatch] };
        } else {
        return { ...col, label: '' }; // insert empty label
        }
    });
    console.log(labelCols)
```

I'm hopping my JSON will shape up like this:

```
const cols = [
            [{labelId:'1', value:'One'},{labelId:'2', value:'Two'}],
            [{labelId:'1', value:'Three'},{}],
            [{},{labelId:'2', value:'Four'}]
         ]
```

Let me know if anyone can come up with better solution

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to "merge" your objects then generate table rows out of them. Considering your objects are actually like these:

```
  const labels = [{label: 'test1', labelId:'1'},{label: 'test2', labelId:'2'}];
  const cols = [{labelId:'1', value:'One'},
                {labelId:'2', value:'Two'},
                {labelId:'3', value:'Three'},
                {labelId:'4', value:'Four'},
              ];

  const labelCols = cols.map(col => {
    const arrayOfMatch = labels.findIndex(label => label.labelId === col.labelId);
    if(arrayOfMatch !== -1) { //matching label exists
      return { ...col, ...labels[arrayOfMatch] };
    } else {
      return { ...col, label: '' }; // insert empty label
    }
  });
```

`labelCols` will be containing something like this:

```
labelCols = [{labelId:'1', value:'One', label: 'test1'},
             {labelId:'2', value:'Two', label: 'test2'},
             {labelId:'3', value:'Three', label: ''},
             {labelId:'4', value:'Four', label: ''},
            ];
```

Then, if you want to render `td` elements with labels, do this:

```
  <table>
    //other codes
    <tr>
      {labelCols.map(item => <td>{item.label}</td>)}
    </tr>
    //other codes
  </table>
```

Comment: Awesome! yeah that's what i want, lemme try it

Comment: Hey Sandy, thanks for the solution, i think im almost there but i realised that i've pasted in the wrong code, so here's my issue i'm able to pump in the label into each object inside an array, but i can't seems to pump in dummy object just to ensure it fill in void <td></td>, just wondering if you'll be able to help me to solve my additional issue, thanks heaps again!

Comment: I just have, let me know if it's still unclear. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
// For comparing two array, array must be with same type of same length
var isEqualArray = labels.map((label)=>{
    cols.map((col)=> label.labelId === col.labelId)
}).filer((item) => item === true)
  .length === labels.length;


if (isEqualArray ) {
    // Equal
}
```